# Why isn't `typename` required for a base class that is a nested type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've been very surprised to see that it is not necessary to add `typename` when a dependent type appears as a base class:

```
struct B {};

struct wr
{ typedef B type; };

template<class T>
struct A : T::type
{};

int main()
{
    A<wr> a;
    (void)a;
}
```

Why isn't `typename` required in front of `T::type`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a special case, as others noted. To quote the standard on this:

> **[temp.res]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#5) A qualified name used as the name in a class-or-decltype or an
>   elaborated-type-specifier is implicitly assumed to name a type,
>   without the use of the typename keyword. In a nested-name-specifier
>   that immediately contains a nested-name-specifier that depends on a
>   template parameter, the identifier or simple-template-id is implicitly
>   assumed to name a type, without the use of the typename keyword.
>   [ Note: The typename keyword is not permitted by the syntax of these
>   constructs.  — end note ]

And come C++20, there will be be even more exceptions to the need for `typename`.

Comment: What other exceptions will there be?

Comment: @0x499602D2 - Function return types, type arguments to the various *_cast operators and default template arguments to name a couple. [The paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) has examples and exact details.

Answer (score 19):

> Why isn't `typename` required in front of `T::type`?

Because you cannot inherit from a value. You use `typename` to tell the compiler that a given nested identifier is a type, but for inheritance, that must be the case anyhow so you can omit it - that's why the language provides an exception to the `typename`- rule for base-specifiers. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) (emphasis mine):

> **The `typename` disambiguator for dependent names**
>
> In a declaration or a definition of a template, including alias template, a name that is not a member of the current instantiation and is dependent on a template parameter is not considered to be a type unless the keyword typename is used or **unless it was already established as a type name**, e.g. with a typedef declaration or **by being used to name a base class**.

Note that we will get more places where `typename` can be omitted, see [P0634](https://wg21.link/p0634).

Answer (score 5):

You only need to use `typename` if you need to tell the compiler to expect a type rather than something else.

Since only a type can be inherited from, there is no ambiguity, and so `typename` is superfluous.